# Semaphore not sharing value betweens processes

Tags: c, process, semaphore

I have a problem with my code. I'm creating a child process with a `fork()` and calling `sem_wait` to decrement the value of the semaphore. But the child still prints 1 as a value for the semaphore.

Do I have to create a shared memory space to use semaphore between processes?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <semaphore.h>


int  A = 0;
sem_t semA;

int main()

{

sem_init(&semA, 1, 1);

if(fork()==0)
{
    sleep(3);
    sem_getvalue(&semA,&A);
    printf("SemA Value child: %d\n",A);
    exit(0);
}
else{

    sem_wait(&semA);
    sem_getvalue(&semA,&A);
    printf("SemA Value parent : %d\n",A);

}
    
wait(NULL);

return 0;
}

 


/*Output : 
SemA Value parent : 0
SemA Value child: 1*/
```

Comment: *Do I have to create a shared memory space to use semaphore between processes?* Yes. Or use a named semaphore.

Comment: add posix or linux tag.